# Is there a way to automate the sending of an Event Participants list?

Tags: civievent

Has anyone found a way to automate the sending of an Event Participant list so that it happens at a set time before the event and to a set group of email addresses (that doesn't change but can be modified)?

Comment: i don't think there is a way to do this out of the box. CiviReports gets you close but probably can't do 'relative date to the event date'. so this would require a customisation such as an extension

Comment: CiviRules (2.19) does allow you to send out emails based on relative date to an event type, you might combine that with a link to the report.